# Spring-boot: Spring-boot web application (Rest API) WAR file is not running

Tags: spring-boot, rest, war

I have followed multiple videos and documents to create WAR file for spring boot web application.
When I run the application as JAVA application from eclipes it works fine but  if I copy the WAR file in webapps folder of tomcat it doesn't work.

Here is the pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <start-class>com.demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the java file

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
          return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting app");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Waiting in app");
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("reached REST API");
        return "App running";
    }
}
```

I am using the url localhost:8080/demo/test but it always gives me error 404.
My System.out.println are logging while running the program from eclipse as Java application but those loggings don't come while deploying WAR in tomcat though catalina.out shows demo.war is successfully deployed and I see the demo directory is created with my DemoApplication class as expected.

I have not created any web.xml. During the project creation I chose wizard "spring starter project" and then in spring starter project dependencies I have selected only "spring-web".

What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated.

**Catalina.out**

> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.4
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.749 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 5 2021 11:07:15 UTC
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.749 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.4.0
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.749 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282-1\jre
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_282-b08
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Red Hat, Inc.
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.761 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.761 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\temp
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\conf\logging.properties
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: abort
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:50.766 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282-1\jre\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Encryption;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-11-openjdk-11.0.10-1\bin;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282-1\bin;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282-1\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:51.036 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:51.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [450] milliseconds
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:51.075 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:51.076 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.4]
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:51.098 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\webapps\testp.war]
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:53.234 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.302 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,040] milliseconds.
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.318 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\webapps\demo.war] has finished in [3,220] ms
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.319 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\webapps\manager]
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [46] ms
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\webapps\ROOT]
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.398 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [33] ms
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.401 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.415 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [3363] milliseconds

**localhost-access-log**
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [04/Apr/2021:23:19:25 +0530] "GET /demo/test HTTP/1.1" 404 764

**tomcat10-stdout**
2021-04-04 23:16:50 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized.

**tomcat10-stderr** last few lines

04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\webapps\ROOT]
04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.398 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [33] ms
04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.401 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Apr-2021 23:16:54.415 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [3363] milliseconds

Comment: what is displayed in tomcat logs?

Comment: updated the tomcat logs

Comment: Everything seems fine. as it is just a demo code you push it to a public repo? i will give a try

Comment: The issue got resolved after replacing tomcat 10 with tomcat 9

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Tomcat 10 changed from Java EE to Jakarta EE. Spring does not support Jakarta EE yet. Jakarta EE support is planned for Spring6 and SpringBoot3 expected at the end of the year.

You have two ways.

1. Deploy the war to the `webapps-javaee` directory instead of the `webapps` directory. Tomcat will convert it automatically using a conversion tool. I solved the same problem with this.
2. Use Tomcat 9 with Java EE support

Below are some of the changes in Tomcat 10.

> The Apache Tomcat Project is proud to announce the release of version 10.0.13 of Apache Tomcat. This release implements specifications that are part of the Jakarta EE 9 platform.
>
> Applications that run on Tomcat 9 and earlier will not run on Tomcat 10 without changes. Java EE based applications designed for Tomcat 9 and earlier may be placed in the $CATALINA_BASE/webapps-javaee directory and Tomcat will automatically convert them to Jakarta EE and copy them to the webapps directory. This conversion is performed using the Apache Tomcat migration tool for Jakarta EE tool which is also available as a separate download for off-line use.
>
> The notable changes in this release are:
>
> Experimental OpenSSL support through the Panama API incubating in Java 17, with support for OpenSSL 1.1+
> Add support for custom caching strategies for web application resources. This initial implementation allows control over whether or not a resource is cached.
> Improve robustness of JNDIRealm for exceptions occurring when getting the connection.
> Full details of these changes, and all the other changes, are available in the Tomcat 10 changelog.

Comment: I have the same problem now in September 2023. I use tomcat 10 and the latest Spring Boot 3.1.3. I thought it should work now because Jakarta EE is supported by Spring in the latest versions.

Comment: I found it. My SpringApplication class has to extend SpringBootServletInitializer and it starts working.

Answer (score -1):

The issue got resolved after replacing tomcat 10 with tomcat 9.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, issue got resolved after replacing tomcat 10 with tomcat 9.